# Definition com.adobe.cairngorm.vo.IValueObject could not found

Tags: apache-royale

i am unable to include external ".swc" files in compilation time.
Please help me? or suggest alternative ways? i am using sevaral 3rd party swc files , so is right choice to migrate my application to apache royale ?

Comment: What swc do you want to include ? Does this swc was build previously with Apache Royale or is it Flex swc ? 
You cannot just like that add to Apache Royale - swc from Flex, cause it has dependency to Flash.

Comment: Cairngorm has Flash dependencies as Piotr says, so it will need a migration itself. PureMVC is not dependent on Flash APIs, so is ready for you to use. We're this days starting to create/migrate something like Swiz Frameworks. I hope it will be ready between a month or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Royale is not 100% compatible with Flex so you'll need to do some research on the libraries you use and what they're counterparts in Royale are.

Cairngorm for instance, has not been ported to Royale, but PureMVC has.